# Merge two regexes

Tags: java, regex

I've written the following regular expression:

[(?:.*[sS]trony [Ll]okalne(?: GW -)? )(.+)(?: nr.+)](https://regex101.com/r/l0tb0h/1/)

It aims at matching what is between `strony lokalne GW -`  and its variants (left site of string) and `nr` (right site of string). In my test cases, this regex is valid. I use `$1` to get my capture group. Please have a look at what it captures (between ** and **).

```
strony lokalne GW - **Częstochowa** nr 28
[ DLO SZ ] - Strony Lokalne **Szczecin** nr 
strony lokalne GW - **Olsztyn** nr 111
[ DLO KI ] - strony lokalne GW - **Kielce** nr 270,
strony lokalne GW - **Łódź** nr 17, 
[ DLO SZ ] - Strony Lokalne **Szczecin** nr 72, 
strony lokalne GW - **Warszawa** nr 125, 
[ DLO KR ] - strony lokalne GW - **Kraków** nr 5, 
[ DLO WA ] - Strony Lokalne **Warszawa** nr 152, 
strony lokalne GW - **Zielona G?a** nr 128, 
strony lokalne GW - **Łódź** nr 63,
```

I have written another regex to capture (similar group) as I wasn't able to do so in one go (i.e. using one regex). Here's my second regex:

[(?:GW -? ?)(.+)(?: nr.+)](http://(?:GW%20-?%20?)(.%20)(?:%20nr.%20))

This time matching is really simple: I need what comes after `GW`  and is before  `nr`.
Some examples are here below:

```
GW **Szczecin** nr 50\n"
GW **TORUŃ** nr 96, wydanie z dnia 23/04/2004WYDARZENIA, str. 3\n"
GW **Lublin** nr 33, wydanie z dnia 08/02/2006WYDARZENIA , str. 3\n"
GW **Wrocław** nr 45, wydanie z dnia 23/02/2004WYDARZENIA, str. 3\n"
```

How do I merge those two regexes?

To get my capture group I use in Java: matcher.replaceAll("$1"), where `matcher` is matcher object from regex pattern.

Comment: Please don't put code into an `href`; it's detrimental to readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep your current approach you can use

```java
.*?\b(?:[sS]trony\s+[lL]okalne(?:\s+GW\s+-)?|GW)\s*(.*?)\s*nr.*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ja9TWx/7). *Details*:

- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `[sS]trony\s+[lL]okalne`  - `Strony`/`strony`, 1+ whitespaces, `lokalne`/`Lokalne`
  - `(?:\s+GW\s+-)?|GW)` - either one or more whitespaces, `GW`, 1+ whitespaces, `-`, *or* a `GW` word
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 (`$1` in the replacement pattern refers to this group value): zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s*nr.*` - zero or more whitespaces, `nr`, and zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.

Another approach is to use a regex for extraction,

```java
\b(?:[sS]trony\s+[lL]okalne(?:\s+GW\s+-)?|GW)\s+(.*?)\s+nr\b
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ja9TWx/5). See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/UBPjJt):

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        List<String> strs = Arrays.asList(
            "strony lokalne GW - Częstochowa nr 28","[ DLO SZ ] - Strony Lokalne Szczecin nr ","strony lokalne GW - Olsztyn nr 111","[ DLO KI ] - strony lokalne GW - Kielce nr 270,","strony lokalne GW - Łódź nr 17, ","[ DLO SZ ] - Strony Lokalne Szczecin nr 72, ","strony lokalne GW - Warszawa nr 125, ","[ DLO KR ] - strony lokalne GW - Kraków nr 5, ","[ DLO WA ] - Strony Lokalne Warszawa nr 152, ","strony lokalne GW - Zielona G?a nr 128, ","strony lokalne GW - Łódź nr 63, ","","GW Szczecin nr 50","GW TORUŃ nr 96, wydanie z dnia 23/04/2004WYDARZENIA, str. 3","GW Lublin nr 33, wydanie z dnia 08/02/2006WYDARZENIA , str. 3","GW Wrocław nr 45, wydanie z dnia 23/02/2004WYDARZENIA, str. 3"
        );
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:[sS]trony\\s+[lL]okalne(?:\\s+GW\\s+-)?|GW)\\s+(.*?)\\s+nr\\b");
        for (String str : strs) {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
            if (m.find()) {
                System.out.println("\"" + str + "\" => " + m.group(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
"strony lokalne GW - Częstochowa nr 28" => Częstochowa
"[ DLO SZ ] - Strony Lokalne Szczecin nr " => Szczecin
"strony lokalne GW - Olsztyn nr 111" => Olsztyn
"[ DLO KI ] - strony lokalne GW - Kielce nr 270," => Kielce
"strony lokalne GW - Łódź nr 17, " => Łódź
"[ DLO SZ ] - Strony Lokalne Szczecin nr 72, " => Szczecin
"strony lokalne GW - Warszawa nr 125, " => Warszawa
"[ DLO KR ] - strony lokalne GW - Kraków nr 5, " => Kraków
"[ DLO WA ] - Strony Lokalne Warszawa nr 152, " => Warszawa
"strony lokalne GW - Zielona G?a nr 128, " => Zielona G?a
"strony lokalne GW - Łódź nr 63, " => Łódź
"GW Szczecin nr 50" => Szczecin
"GW TORUŃ nr 96, wydanie z dnia 23/04/2004WYDARZENIA, str. 3" => TORUŃ
"GW Lublin nr 33, wydanie z dnia 08/02/2006WYDARZENIA , str. 3" => Lublin
"GW Wrocław nr 45, wydanie z dnia 23/02/2004WYDARZENIA, str. 3" => Wrocław
```

Comment: Dear Wiktor, many thanks. I tried your first solution, but it captures what I don't like to be captured. In this string `Gazeta Wyborcza nr 272`, group `Gazeta Wyborcza` is captured, but it shouldn't. Would you be so kind to take it into account in your regex? Basically, string should start with `GW` or with have some form of `strony lokalne`.

Comment: @menteith The [second approach](https://regex101.com/r/Ja9TWx/6) works. And [here is the first one](https://regex101.com/r/Ja9TWx/7) - updated.